# Android Studio OSM Object Verifier

Tags: java, kotlin, openstreetmap

How can I fix an error in my Activity_Summarize.java? I am trying to build a system that will find a given point using radius in Open Street Map and take out the nearest node.
Then the object should be picked out from the point (church, school, etc.).
In Logcat, only No nearest point found is returned.
I program in German.

[Code](https://pastebin.com/JLPzqtvx)

Fixing small parts of the project would be great.

```
package org.flaggshipp.kusa_android;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Toast;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton;
import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.Query;
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;

import org.osmdroid.api.IMapController;
import org.osmdroid.views.MapView;
import org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser;
import org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException;
import org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserFactory;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.StringReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Collections;

public class Activity_Summarize extends AppCompatActivity {

    RecyclerView recyclerView;
    DatabaseReference database;

    FirebaseDatabase database1 = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    MyAdapter myAdapter;
    ArrayList<Text> list;
    LinearLayoutManager mLayoutManager;
    long timestamp = System.currentTimeMillis();
    DatabaseReference myRef = database1.getReference("Users");
    private FloatingActionButton flbtn;
    private IMapController mapController;

    private MapView mapView;
    private final String overpassApiUrl = "https://overpass-api.de/api/interpreter";
    private final String osmQueryTemplate = "[out:json];node[amenity=place_of_worship](around:100,%s,%s);out;";

    double latitude = 50.7865342;
    double longitude = 12.7212223;


    @SuppressLint("MissingInflatedId")
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_summarize);

        // Beispiel-Koordinaten (ersetze sie durch deine tatsächlichen Koordinaten)


        double radiusInMeters = 20.0;

        // Umrechnung von Metern in Grad
        double radiusInDegrees = metersToDegrees(latitude, radiusInMeters);


        new OverpassQueryTask().execute(latitude, longitude);

        SharedUtil.Companion.initialize((Context)this);
        if (SharedUtil.Companion.isRegistrated()) {
            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            //bundle.putString("username", SharedUtil.Companion.getValue("username"));
            //bundle.putString("password", SharedUtil.Companion.getValue("password"));
        }

        flbtn = findViewById(R.id.fbtn);
        flbtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                addDatatoFirebase();
            }
        });

        String username = SharedUtil.Companion.getValue("username");

        mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(Activity_Summarize.this);
        recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerview);
        database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users").child(username).child("signs");
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);

        list = new ArrayList<>();
        myAdapter = new MyAdapter(list, Activity_Summarize.this);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(myAdapter);

        loadKeysFromFirebase();
    }

    private class OverpassQueryTask extends AsyncTask<Double, Void, String> {

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Double... params) {
            double latitude = params[0];
            double longitude = params[1];

            String overpassUrl = "https://overpass-api.de/api/interpreter?data=node(around:10," +
                    latitude + "," + longitude + ");out count;";

            try {
                URL url = new URL(overpassUrl);
                HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));
                StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
                String line;

                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    result.append(line);
                }

                reader.close();
                return result.toString();

            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e("OverpassQueryTask", "Error querying Overpass API", e);
            }

            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            if (result != null && !result.isEmpty()) {
                // Extrahiere den nächstgelegenen Punkt
                String nearestNodeId = extractNearestNodeId(result);

                if (nearestNodeId != null && !nearestNodeId.isEmpty()) {
                    // Führe eine weitere Abfrage durch, um Informationen über den nächsten Punkt zu erhalten
                    new OverpassQueryTask().execute(Double.valueOf(nearestNodeId));
                } else {
                    Log.e("OverpassQueryTask", "Kein nächstgelegener Punkt gefunden");
                }
            } else {
                Log.e("OverpassQueryTask", "Overpass API query returned no results or null");
            }
        }
    }

    private void showToast(String message) {
        Toast.makeText(this, message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    private double metersToDegrees(double latitude, double meters) {
        return meters / (111.32 * 1000 * Math.cos(Math.toRadians(latitude)));
    }

    private void addDatatoFirebase() {
        //Calendar / Date and Time Values
        String username = SharedUtil.Companion.getValue("username");

        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.setTimeInMillis(timestamp);
        SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss");
        String dateTime = simpleDateFormat.format(calendar.getTime());

        //IP-Adresse abfrage
        //WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(WIFI_SERVICE);
        //int ipAddress = wifiManager.getConnectionInfo().getIpAddress();
        //String ipString = String.format("%d.%d.%d.%d", (ipAddress & 0xff), (ipAddress >> 8 & 0xff), (ipAddress >> 16 & 0xff), (ipAddress >> 24 & 0xff));

        // below 3 lines of code is used to set
        // data in our object class.
        //Entries.setText(wText);
        Entries.setDate(dateTime);

        myRef.child(username).child("signs").child(String.valueOf(timestamp)).child("text").setValue("Unterschrift: Oberlungwitz");
        myRef.child(username).child("signs").child(String.valueOf(timestamp)).child("date").setValue(dateTime);
        //myRef.child(username).child("signs").child(String.valueOf(timestamp)).setValue("Unterschrift: Oberlungwitz");
        //myRef.child(username).child("date").setValue(dateTime);
        myRef.child(username).child("signs").child(String.valueOf(timestamp)).child("unixtime").setValue(timestamp);
        //myRef.child(username).child("ip-adresse").setValue(ipString);
        // we are use add value event listener method
        // which is called with database reference.
        myRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                // inside the method of on Data change we are setting
                // our object class to our database reference.
                // data base reference will sends data to firebase.
                for (DataSnapshot dataSnapshot : snapshot.getChildren()) {

                    //Messages userName = dataSnapshot.getValue(Messages.class);
                    //list.add(userName);

                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {
                // if the data is not added or it is cancelled then
                // we are displaying a failure toast message.
                Toast.makeText(Activity_Summarize.this, "Fail to add data" + error, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }

    private void loadKeysFromFirebase() {
        Query query = database.orderByChild("unixtime").limitToLast(3);

        query.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                list.clear();

                for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {

                    Text text = snapshot.getValue(Text.class);
                    list.add(text);

                }

                Collections.reverse(list);

                myAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
                Log.e("Firebase", "Error loading keys from Firebase", databaseError.toException());
            }
        });
    }

    private String extractNearestNodeId(String xml) {
        try {
            XmlPullParserFactory factory = XmlPullParserFactory.newInstance();
            XmlPullParser parser = factory.newPullParser();
            parser.setInput(new StringReader(xml));

            int eventType = parser.getEventType();
            double minDistance = Double.MAX_VALUE;
            String nearestNodeId = null;

            while (eventType != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT) {
                if (eventType == XmlPullParser.START_TAG && parser.getName().equals("node")) {
                    double nodeLat = Double.parseDouble(parser.getAttributeValue(null, "lat"));
                    double nodeLon = Double.parseDouble(parser.getAttributeValue(null, "lon"));

                    double distance = calculateDistance(latitude, longitude, nodeLat, nodeLon);

                    if (distance < minDistance) {
                        minDistance = distance;
                        nearestNodeId = parser.getAttributeValue(null, "id");
                    }
                }
                eventType = parser.next();
            }

            return nearestNodeId;
        } catch (XmlPullParserException | IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }

    private double calculateDistance(double lat1, double lon1, double lat2, double lon2) {
        // Einfache Berechnung der Entfernung als euklidische Distanz
        return Math.sqrt(Math.pow(lat2 - lat1, 2) + Math.pow(lon2 - lon1, 2));
    }

}
```

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).